# Can I webscrape other website inside my html document using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, asynchronous, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape other website so I can show content from that website on mine website. I wrote JavaScript code that works but not when I start it onClick on website

```
var button = document.getElementById("scrape-website");

button.onclick = async function scrapeProduct() {

    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("gimnazija-fgalovic.hr/");

    const [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/img');
    const src = await el.getProperty("src");
    const articleImage = await src.jsonValue();

    const [el2] = await page.$x('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/h3/a');
    const txt = await el2.getProperty("textContent");
    const articleTitle = await txt.jsonValue();

    const [el3] = await page.$x('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/span[2]/time');
    const txt2 = await el3.getProperty("textContent");
    const articleDate = await txt2.jsonValue();

    if (titlePrevious !== articleTitle) {
        console.log({articleImage, articleTitle, articleDate});
        document.write(articleTitle);
    }

    browser.close();
}
```

This is HTML code for button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/scrapeAndWrite.js"></script>

<button class="scrape" id="scrape-website" type="button" onClick="scrapeProduct()">
Scrape
</button>
```

This is error I am getting inside console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: scrapeProduct is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use tools like Webpack to convert modules using the Node.js module system into code that can run in a browser, it can't support modules which depend on features that are only provided by Node.js (such as the ability to run a headless version of Chrome like `puppeteer`).

You can't run this code in the browser.

The closest you could get would be to write a web service using Node.js and then call it using Ajax.